# Calling method from Fragment inside another Fragment

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have 2 fragments with methods. Now I want to call a method from Fragment2.cs inside Fragment1.cs. Here is the method from Fragment2.cs:

```
public void UpdateActionBar(int CurrentFragmentNum)
{
    if (CurrentFragmentNum == 1)
    {
        btnBack.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        btnNext.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    }
    else
    {
        btnBack.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        btnNext.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }

    if (CurrentFragmentNum == 3)
    {
        btnNext.Text = "Finish";
    }
    else
    {
        btnNext.Text = "Next";
    }
}
```

And in Fragment1.cs I need to call this method! How can I do that... I already know how to call a method from the MainActivity using this:

```
(Activity as MainActivity)?.Method();
```

But now I want the method from another fragment.

I have already tried something like this:

```
(Fragment as Fragment2)?.Method();
```

But that gives me the error:

> 'Fragment' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried and what error are you getting?

Comment: Added to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make search before ask, the question is very popular

[google search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=VuzZXMjEGIiGk74P7sWe8AI&q=xamarin+android+fragment+communication&oq=xamarin+android+fragment+communication&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39.16099.16099..16313...0.0..0.146.146.0j1......0....1..gws-wiz.CEQh536hlkA)

Comment: Thanks, I already found it, but can you please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120534/calling-a-method-from-a-different-class-that-uses-variables-outside-the-method