# Calling a method from a different class that uses variables outside the method

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have a problem. I have a method in a class like this:

```
public void UpdateActionBar(int CurrentFragmentNum)
{
    if (CurrentFragmentNum == 1)
    {
        btnBack.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        btnNext.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
    }
    else
    {
        btnBack.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        btnNext.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }

    if (CurrentFragmentNum == 3)
    {
        btnNext.Text = "Finish";
    }
    else
    {
        btnNext.Text = "Next";
    }
}
```

Now in another class I call this method like this:

```
new ActionBar_Setup().UpdateActionBar(CurrentFragmentNum);
```

But as you an see I use the 2 variables: `btnBack` and `btnNext`
Those variables are null when I call the method from a different class, because then the variables are not defined. But I can't move the lines that assign a value to those variables because it uses a view variable. Here is the code to show what I mean:

```
public class ActionBar_Setup : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    Button btnBack;
    Button btnNext;

    public int CurrentFragmentNum = 1;
    public int PreviousFragmentNum = 1;
    public string Direction;

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.setup_nav_bar, container, false);

        btnBack = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBack);
        btnNext = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnNext);

        btnBack.Click += btnBack_Click;
        btnNext.Click += btnNext_Click;

        UpdateActionBar(CurrentFragmentNum);

        return view;
    }

    public void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentFragmentNum > 1)
        {
            PreviousFragmentNum = CurrentFragmentNum;
            CurrentFragmentNum -= 1;
            Direction = "Backwards";
            UpdateActionBar(CurrentFragmentNum);
            (Activity as MainActivity)?.ShowFragment(CurrentFragmentNum, PreviousFragmentNum, Direction);
        }
    }

    public void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentFragmentNum < 3)
        {
            PreviousFragmentNum = CurrentFragmentNum;
            CurrentFragmentNum += 1;
            Direction = "Forwards";
            UpdateActionBar(CurrentFragmentNum);
            (Activity as MainActivity)?.ShowFragment(CurrentFragmentNum, PreviousFragmentNum, Direction);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateActionBar(int CurrentFragmentNum)
    {
        if (CurrentFragmentNum == 1)
        {
            btnBack.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
            btnNext.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
        else
        {
            btnBack.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            btnNext.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }

        if (CurrentFragmentNum == 3)
        {
            btnNext.Text = "Finish";
        }
        else
        {
            btnNext.Text = "Next";
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this, so I can call the function in a different class?

Comment: What results do you want when calling this method from an external class? The simplest fix is to simply check if the controls are set, and exit the method if they're not, i.e: `if (btnBack == null || btnNext == null) return;`

Comment: They will always be null then. I want to change the visibility of those buttons when I call the method outside the class. So I need something that defines the value inside the method again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make your **ActionBar_Setup** singleton:

```
public class ActionBar_Setup : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
 {

    public static ActionBar_Setup Instance;
    public static ActionBar_Setup NewInstance()
    {
        if (Instance== null)
        {
            Instance= new ActionBar_Setup();

        }

        return Instance;
    }
    ...
}
```

then when you create the **ActionBar_Setup**  like this:

```
ActionBar_Setup fActionBarSetup = ActionBar_Setup.NewInstance();
```

finally call **UpdateActionBar** method in other class like this:

```
ActionBar_Setup.Instance.UpdateActionBar(3);
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to call the UpdateActionBar in a different class. Not in ActionBar_Setup.cs, or I don't understand what you mean!?

Comment: you could call like this ActionBar_Setup.Instance.UpdateActionBar(3); in different class,not in  ActionBar_Setup.cs.

Comment: you could try it,and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: I have added it to my code, but when I call the method, `btnBack` and `btnNext` are still `null`?!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters to your button events from the view as a GET or POST values on the button and assign the values to your method directly from the views

Comment: Can you provide me a Sample?

Answer (score 0):

Theyre multiple ways to achieve what you want as per what Ahmed Moawad says. Another possible solution would be to add a btnBack and a btnNext field in the class. Then assign the values to the fields. Once you execute the method. You should be able to grab the fields within the calling method.

I would say seperate the UpdateActionBar method from the form actions. So you'll have your UpdateActionBar in a seperate class as you do. But your btnBack and btnNext fields should probably be named some thing else. Then within the calling method assign the results of your fields to btnNext and btnBack.